# What is in the Android Studio bundle?

Tags: android-studio

When I click `Check for Updates -> Download` in my Android Studio it takes me to http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest/ where there is a download of about 400 MB.

(I don't know why it says "canary" in the URL as I am on the "stable" channel.)

And then there is http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html which would download a file named `android-studio-bundle-143.2790544-windows.exe` which has about 1.2 GB.

What is in this bundle that is missing in the normal download?